# Which time in the Michelson-Morley is longer?

Tags: special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry, aether

The time for the light to travel along the same direction as that of the ether was calculated to be given by the following equation:
\begin{equation}
\label{Eq:I:15:4}
t_1+t_2=\frac{2L/c}{1-u^2/c^2}.
\end{equation}

The time for the light to travel in the other direction should then be defined by:

\begin{equation*}
2t_3=2L/\sqrt{c^2-u^2}.
\end{equation*}

In [this](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_15.html) chapter, Feynman derives these two equations. Now the denominators clearly show that t3 should be greater than t1+t2. However, later on in the chapter, he says: "the time to go to C and back is a little less than the time to E and back."

Like how is that possible? The math clearly shows that the time taken to go to C and back is greater.

Comment: You appear to have dropped the return leg of the `cross-current' calculation.

Answer (score 0):

From B to E and back [the longitudinal direction],
\begin{equation}
t_1+t_2=
\left[ \frac{2Lc}{c^2-u^2} \right]
=\frac{2L/c}{1-u^2/c^2},
\end{equation}
where I have included [in brackets] the preceding equation from the Feynman reference.

From B to C and back [the transverse direction], 
\begin{equation}
\label{Eq:I:15:5}
2t_3=\frac{2L}{\sqrt{c^2-u^2}}=\left[\frac{2L/c}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}\right],
\end{equation}
where I have included [in brackets] the subsequent expression [that you seem to have omitted] from the Feynman reference.

Of course, when using denominators to compare expressions, one has to first use equal numerators. So, as the Feynman reference had been setting up, one should compare the last expressions:
$$t_{BEB}=\frac{2L/c}{1-u^2/c^2} \geq  \frac{2L/c}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}=t_{BCB}.$$

Using $\gamma\equiv\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}$ [where $-c < u < c$],
we have
$$t_{BEB}=\gamma^2 (2L/c) \geq  \gamma(2L/c)=t_{BCB},$$
where the inequality is clearly true since $\gamma \geq 1$.